# Adding words to list

Tags: python

I wrote a function that is supposed to add the words from a `.txt` to a `list` but it is supposed to ignore empty lines, how ever my function outputs `['',]` at an empty line.

```
def words(filename):
    word = []
    file = open(filename)
    for line in file:
        word.append(line.strip())
    return word
```

How can i fix this thanks

Comment: It's good practice to close files that you open. Or open the file in a `with` block so it gets closed automatically.

Comment: i am still working on it, just got stuck at this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for an empty line and skip the append in that case.

```
def words(filename):
    word = []
    file = open(filename)
    for line in file:
        line=line.strip()
        if len(line):
            word.append(line)
    return word
```

Comment: Also, you can just do `if line:`, it's simpler & more efficient that `if len(line)`. And see my comment on the question about closing files.

Answer (score 3):

what about a simple if test?

```
def words(filename):
    word = []
    file = open(filename)
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() != ' ':
            word.append(line.strip())
    return word
```

EDIT: I forgot the .strip() after line
Besides, you could also use `if line.strip():`
Last, if you want to get a list of words but have several words per line, you need to split them. Assuming your separator is ' ':

```
def words(filename):
        word = []
        file = open(filename)
        for line in file:
            if line.strip() != ' ':
                word.extend(line.strip().split())
        return word
```

Comment: Except that wouldn't you consider a line containing whitespace to also be an empty line? One stray ' ' character and you'll still get the empty entries the OP was complaining about

Comment: @heroworkshop thanks, I corrected my answer. Also please note that if you want to get words from sentences, you might need to import 're' and find the right regular expression (mustn't be too complicated)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this like that:

```
def words(filename):
    word = []
    file = open(filename)
    for line in file:
        if not line.strip():
            word.append(line)
    return word
```

Your problem is that you're adding `line.strip()`, but what happens if `line` is actually an empty string? Look:

```
In [1]: line = ''

In [2]: line.strip()
Out[2]: ''
```

`''.strip()` returns an empty string.

Comment: I think the OP wants to append the stripped line, not the unstripped line.

Comment: @PM2Ring If that's the case I believe OP is able to change to `word.append(line.strip()`.